# Choosing an SMD JFET

Tags: surface-mount, jfet

I've prototyped a simple circuit for interfacing a ceramic mic to an iPad. It uses a 2N5457 JFET. I just happened to have that component on hand and it worked well.

I'd like to implement this circuit using a surface-mount JFET, but frankly don't have the expertise to pick out one which is likely to work for me. The main issues are the low supply voltage (about 2.2V) and a signal voltage of about 0.1V. The frequency range is just audio.

Can anyone advise me on what parameters I should be looking at in the spec sheets, or even better, suggest a suitable SMD JFET?

Comment: You do something called a *parameteric search*.

Comment: Already back in 1997 Fairchild Semiconductors made the  2N5457 in an SMD package.

Answer (score 7):

> I'd like to implement this circuit using a surface-mount JFET, but
>   frankly don't have the expertise to pick out one which is likely to
>   work for me.

I don't know how many people we tell to LOOK AT THE DATASHEET. Front page from ON semiconductor / Fairchild: -

[image]

> Can anyone advise me on what parameters I should be looking at in the
>   spec sheets

Without a schematic of your target circuit, no.

Comment: Thank you for your HELPFUL ANSWER TO MY QUESTION. I have in fact been looking at quite a few datasheets, but I lack the knowledge to make an informed choice based on the overwhelming amount of info in the datasheets. Also, FWIW, the SMD equivalent of the device I used is out of stock at the suppliers available to me.

Comment: Choosing a different supplier for an SMD replacement part is a whole lot easier than choosing a device that is not related to the original part. If your question was all about "how do I understand what data sheet information is useful for device X in circuit Y" then you would get more useful information. However, I don't recommend you to make wholesale changes to this question; instead raise a new question if you are still in difficulties.